# Run Next.js script that uses `fs` & `sharp` in development using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

I am trying to create a simple `GIFPlayer` which shows GIF if someone clicks on a play button otherwise shows a PNG like:

```html
<img className="w-full h-full" src={isPlaying ? gifPath : imgPath} alt={pic.alt} />
```

I only have GIF file so I create PNG file using Node.js `sharp` module.

#### scripts/gif-to-png.js

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const sharp = require('sharp')
const fg = require('fast-glob')

const ROOT_PATH = process.cwd()
const POSTS_PATH = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'src/_posts')

function* walkSync(dir) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            yield* walkSync(path.join(dir, files[i].name))
        } else {
            yield path.join(dir, files[i].name)
        }
    }
}

const gifToPng = async () => {
    try {
        for (let [i, file] of [...walkSync(POSTS_PATH)].entries()) {
            const extname = path.extname(file)
            if (extname === '.gif') {
                const dirname = path.dirname(file)
                const png = path.resolve(dirname, path.basename(file).replace('.gif', '.png'))
                await sharp(file).png().toFile(png)
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error thrown:', e)
    }
}

gifToPng()
```

My `next.config.js` runs this script in development like:

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) => {

        if (!options.dev && options.isServer) {
            .
            .
            .
        } else {
            const originalEntry = config.entry

            config.entry = async () => {
                const entries = { ...(await originalEntry()) }
                entries['./scripts/gif-to-png'] = './scripts/gif-to-png.js'
                return entries
            }
        }

        return config
    },
}
```

However, its throwing error saying:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

The reason I need this script in **development** instead of **production** is I need to see the PNG file in `development` as well. Otherwise I won't be able to see it if it only runs in **production**.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/27525#discussioncomment-1061696).

The following tells `webpack` to not try and use `fs` on the client build (since that will fail).

```
if (!options.isServer) {
  config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
}
return config
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) => {

            if (!options.dev && options.isServer) {
                    .
                    .
                    .
            } else {
                    const originalEntry = config.entry

                    config.entry = async () => {
                            const entries = { ...(await originalEntry()) }
                            entries['./scripts/gif-to-png'] = './scripts/gif-to-png.js'
                            return entries
                    }
            }

            
            if (!options.isServer) {
                config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
            }

            return config
    },
}
```